# Socket.io reconnect messes up automatic attempts

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I use socket.io automatic attemps to reconnect if it could not couldn't for any reason.

But sometimes, I disconnect the socket myself and reconnect it a moment after using the reconnect() function. If the `socket.reconnect()` function is called, I am under the impression that it stops the automatic attempts to reconnect.

Is there an option that I can use so it keeps on trying until it can connect?

Comment: Don't use `reconnect()`.  Just make a new connection from scratch.

Comment: @jfriend00 why is that? Is there recommendations against using reconnect somewhere? I can't see how reinitializing everything could be a best practice :(

Comment: @jfriend00 Ahah, in the code itself, the documentation for socket.io is, well, light...

Comment: Finally found the code for the `.reconnect()` method [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/78f61c3abcc953532ec5c30e1b8cd485b9ea3656/socket.io.js#L4834).  I don't see any evidence in that code that calling it stops future auto-reconnect attempts.  Where did you get that impression from.  FYI, it is clearly marked as a `private API`.